# is possible to do this in php? $code->Info_.$code

Tags: php, savant3

I was looking at several locations, but does not like looking, 
I want to perform this operation

```
$tpl = new Savant3();
$tpl->Info_.$db_code["name"] = $db_code["info"];
$tpl->display('index.tpl.php');

php echo $this->eprint($this->Info_Name);
```

is it possible?. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for this lame comment, devote it if you want, but just try it :)

Comment: I didn`t quite understood you but I`m thinking that you are searching for a variable varible.Try with double $ .. like $$db_code['name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
$tpl->{"Info_$db_code[name]"} = $db_code["info"];
```

see also the manual for this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, completely doable using [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Use a variable containing the function name to access the class function. Consider this:

```
class testClass {
  function randomstring() {
    return 'hello world!';
  }
}
```

And this:

```
$test = new testClass();

// simulate an arbitrary second half of a string/function name
$random_string = 'string';

// build class name into single variable using arbitrary first half
// of string/function name
$class_name = 'random' . $random_string ;
// use that variable (variable variable)
echo $test->{$class_name}(); // hello world!
```

**In your case:** If this is a class property, you'd do this: (if it's a function, add the `()`)

```
$prop_name = 'Info_' . $db_code["name"];
$tpl->{$prop_name} = $db_code["info"];
```